# Why can't I make my URLs rewrite in my htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been messing with this for the last hour... visiting about 20 different Google tuts and I can't seem make my site rewrite the url in any way.  I've even just tried changing .php to .html and I'm not having any luck.

Here's one of my many fails:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule viewItem(.*)\.htm$ /viewItem.php?id=$1
```

For this above one, I'm just trying to change my viewItem.php page to viewItem.html

My ultimate goal is to change hxxp://mydomain.com/viewItem.php?id=900  (as one example of an id) to hxxp://mydomain.com/details/

I'm then going to append the title on the end.  I can do the append in php but being a newb to .htaccess, I'm apparently missing something glaringly obvious.

Any ideas?
Thanks much.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you (for now) want the URL to be http://whatever.com/viewItem.php, and you want to rewrite that to http://whatever.com/viewItem.html (not in the browser's URL bar but just as far as which file gets served)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the 'l' of 'html'?

```
RewriteRule viewItem(.*)\.html?$ /viewItem.php?id=$1
```

Comment: oops.. no.  just forgot to list it here.  it won't change to .htm or .html.  it just won't change!